# How to define custom events and event listeners in Android?

Tags: java, android, events, callback

I'm a starter in Android app development, and my experience in Java development is also minimal.

I'm working on a very basic context-aware application and I want to understand how can I notify my activity class of some custom event? (unlike onClick()). So if I have a class which is responsible for monitoring some resource. (For simplicity, let's assume a Timer  class which monitors time and notifies the Activity class every hour).

How can my activity class 'subscribe' and listen for such events from the Timer class?

I would really appreciate if you provide some code example and perhaps how event handling works in Android/Java. Thanks for your time and help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `Broadcast` Intents to notify listeners of system or application/custom events..

send a `Broadcast` using `sendBroadcast` method whenever your custom event occurs..

```
Intent intent = new Intent(NEW_Intent);
intent.putExtra(“Test”,Test1);
sendBroadcast(intent);
```

To create a new Broadcast Receiver(which will listen to your event/broadcast), extend the `BroadcastReceiver` class and override the `onReceive` event handler.The `onReceive` method will be executed when a `Broadcast` Intent is received that matches the Intent Filter used to register the receiver.

Register your receiver in either Manifest file or in the code..

//in xml

```
<receiver android:name=”.ReceiverName”>
<intent-filter>
<action android:name=”com.paad.action.NEW_INTENT”/>
</intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

//in code..

```
IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter(NEW_INTENT);
ReceiverName r = new ReceiverName();
registerReceiver(r, filter);
```

Comment: before I know much about the broadcast receiver registration, I thought I've to add both of those ( xml and code). But, found that you can do any of these processes, would you please correct this by putting few more words? And, I think NEW_Intent should be available from anywhere. So, would you please add that too?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Intent class:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html